# If IE fork execution of timed function

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I have a code like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            if( getInternetExplorerVersion() != -1){
                //do not friendly IE stuff
                            ie_browsers();          
            }else{
                other_browsers();
            }

                        setInterval(other_browsers, 32000);
        }, 800);
    });
   ...
```

to detect IE i have

```
function getInternetExplorerVersion(){
        var rv = -1;
        if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'){
            var ua = navigator.userAgent;
            var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
            if (re.exec(ua) != null)
                 rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
        }
           return rv;
    }
```

My question is where do I have to put the instruction `setInterval(other_browsers, 32000);`?

Do I have to put it inside else statement and other `ie_browsers();` inside if?

the purpose is to execute every 32 seconds the function with a delay of 800 miliseconds..

Comment: This is generally a bad idea, both the interval and the browser sniffing. Create code that does feature detection, or use a library like modernizer instead !

Comment: well, the issue here is I need to patch IE functionality, all browsers work perfect...

Comment: "$(function () {...}}" is shorthand for $(document).ready(function(){...}) and you are nesting it

Comment: What is the IE functionality you are trying to patch?

Comment: IE is not a web-kit browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The questionable nature of this in general aside (I'll leave that for the comments).  If I'm understanding what you're asking, you can do the following to avoid duplicating your `setInterval` in the `if` and the `else`:

```
$(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        var func;
        if( getInternetExplorerVersion() != -1){
            //do not friendly IE stuff
            func = ie_browsers;
        }else{
            func = other_browsers;
        }

        // call once now
        func();

        // call repeatedly on an interval
        setInterval(func, 32000);
    }, 800);
});
```